# Filter for When Price of one column is above another column for X consecutive days - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a sammple dataframe below.

In this case, I want to filter for when `Close` has been above `sma10` for X consecutive days.
For this example we can use  8 consecutive days

I know about using `close.shift(1)`, but is there a better way than writing it out manually:
`condition = (close.shift(1) > 10sma.shift(1)) &close.shift(2)....close.shift(7) > 10sma.shift(87)`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate sample data
np.random.seed(123)
dates = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', periods=100)
prices = np.random.rand(100) * 100
sma_10 = pd.Series(prices).rolling(window=10).mean()
ohlc_data = np.random.rand(100, 4) * 100

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(ohlc_data, columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
df['Date'] = dates
df.loc[9:20, 'Close'] = 80

df['SMA_10'] = sma_10

# Print sample DataFrame
print(df.head(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `cumsum` , this will split the each trend into different groups, then you can `groupby` and filter with group `count`

```
m = df['Close'].gt(df['SMA_10'])
days = 8
out = df[m.groupby((~m).cumsum()).transform('count').eq(days+1) & m].copy()
```